# how do i send a print('somethin') in node red using python function node?

Tags: python, node-red

i want to have a simple flow in node red that prints a string to the debug console in node red. I have tried the below code in a python function node and that is connected to a debug node, when i click on python function node, i expect 1.23456 to be printed to debug console. I get nothing?

```
val = 1.23456
node.log (msg);
msg['payload'] = val
return msg
```

Comment: Why would you expect to see `1.23456` since you don't set `msg.payload` until after you've logged it

Comment: I don't understand....do i need to set 'msg.payload = 1.23456' ? and then it will send that to debug node?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize you need to use a inject node to inject a flow into the python function node to get the flow to work.